# F# source code documentation of the standard library

Tags: f#

I learned most of my haskell knowledge by browsing though the Haskell docs with source code http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.2.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v%3Ahead

But I couldn't find the source code of common F# libraries, I only found the docs on how to use them like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370406.aspx

Is there something like hackage for F#?

Comment: I will say that some of the compiler source is very cryptic - and often uses code that isn't allowed in user-facing code (in particular prim-types.fs).  So be careful if you are reading the source to learn F#.  You might be better off looking at some of the more popular F# projects on github

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an open-source edition of the F# compiler and core library available on [GitHub](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp).